# New modules are not shown in menu with XavaPro

Tags: java, jpa, openxava

When I upgrade my OpenXava application to XavaPro, all modules of my application are available in XavaPro automatically. That is, if I have three modules, Customer, Invoice and Product, thoses modules are in the left menu in XavaPro. That's perfect.

However, if I add a new module to my application, writing a new JPA entity, in this way:

```
@Entity
public class Order {
  // ...
}
```

While in a plain OpenXava application Order would be added to the left menu, with XavaPro the Order module is not shown in the menu:

[image: New module not shown in the menu]

The module is not shown, even if I declare it explicitly in application.xml.

How can I show new modules in the menu with XavaPro?

Answer (score 0):

On upgrading your application from OpenXava to XavaPro, XavaPro creates a role called 'user' and add to it all the modules of your application. After that moment, you have to add explicitly your new modules to the role 'user' or any other role. It works in this way to avoid to expose modules to not authorized users inadvertently, just because we have added some code and deploy it to production.

To add the new modules to the left menu, go to the Roles module (inside Admin folder). There choose the 'user' role. Then in the detail click on Add in the Modules list, choose your new module, Order in this case, and it will be done:

[image: Add module to role user]

After it your users will see the Order module.